# SBT scala project error : value is not a member of object

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala-java-interop

I am scala beginner.

I have created a scala sbt project.

I have a scala program **Apple.scala** under package `com.development.bigdata.executor`

I have a another java project created using maven. It has a class as **FruitInfo** in package `com.development.bigdata.provider`,
under that I wrote a simple method

```
public String getInfo(String fruit) 
{
   return fruit;
}
```

I want to call java's `getInfo()` method from **Apple.scala**

I compiled FruitInfo java class and added jar dependency in scala project

But when I actually call the method from Apple.scala -

```
val info : FruitInfo = new FruitInfo()
    info.getInfo("apple")
```

When I do `sbt clean package`, it throws an error saying,

> value getInfo is not a member of object
>   com.development.bigdata.privider.FruitInfo

My build.sbt is like -

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.0" % "provided",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.10",
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5.1",
  "com.development.bigdata.provider" % "metadata-manager" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

Any idea whats happening? Please let me know. Suggestions are really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `FruitInfo` defined?

Comment: package com.development.bigdata.provider

public class FruitInfo
{

}

Comment: You define a method `getFruit` but call `getInfo`?

Comment: sorry.. that was typo while posting here. its getInfo() only

Comment: Did you check inside the JAR you created with Maven to see that the method is actually there?

Comment: yes.. it is there.. i can access getInfo() method from ide.. it throws at runtime when I do sbt clean package

Comment: Oh, you're trying to create an uber JAR with all the dependencies?

Comment: Yes. does this matter? I want to call java method from scala